# no supported authentication methods available public key

Tags: ssh, debian, putty

First of all im sorry for my bad english:)
I have a school project server - debian 8 jessie.
I created user named tester for my friend and he gave me his authorized_key file. I uploaded it to his folder to .ssh folder.
Then i used these commands
chown tester:tester /home/tester/
chown tester:tester /home/tester/.ssh/
chown tester:tester /home/tester/.ssh/authorized_keys

But when he tries to connect, he is disconnected with that error. I tried to take my authorized_key file and copy it there and then i tried to connect as tester by myself but it says the same error.

Im really newbie at this, i would be happy for any help... because for me it doesnt make any sence... i can connect as myself with my key but when give my key to tester and try to connect as him it fails... i dont get that.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the file system permissions differ between the two accounts? Note that the permissions of the file itself _and_ of the `.ssh` folder are important. Please take a look into the servers system log, you might be able to see a related message when attempting a login.

Comment: I tried these commands to give tester his permisions in his home folder
chmod go-rx /home/tester
chmod go-rx /home/tester/.ssh

How can i see that message when attempting to login pls ? :) im really newbie

Comment: On a debian system the system log is usually found in `/etc/syslog` or similar. You can use `tail -f /etc/syslog` then and see any additional lines when making a live login request.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. For problems with general-purpose utilities like ssh, you should consider asking this on [su] instead of here. When you do, you should include the relevant information _as text_ in your question instead of pictures.